# Pushing downloads from server to client is removing lines from txt files and other documents

Tags: php, download, fopen

I have a download class that seems to have begun removing line breaks from files when pushing the file to the client for download.

```
    public function download()
    {
        $file = $this->decrypt($_GET['filepath']);
        $file = my_utility::urlesc($file, true);
        if(!is_file($file)) die('Sorry. That file could not be found.');
        $name = basename($file);
        $size = filesize($file);
        $mime = $this->mimes(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1)));
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: ".$mime);
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
        header("Content-Length: " . $size);
        if(ob_get_contents()) ob_end_flush();
        set_time_limit(0);
        $file = @fopen($file, 'rb');
        if($file)
        {
            while(!feof($file))
            {
                print(fread($file, 1024*8));
                if(connection_status()!=0)
                {
                    @fclose($file);
                    die();
                }
            }
            @fclose($file);
        }
        die();          
    }
```

Example original `.txt` file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Sed vel facilisis elit. Suspendisse et commodo justo. 

Nunc semper, neque non pulvinar interdum, erat ex laoreet lacus.
```

`.txt` file after download:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel facilisis elit. Suspendisse et commodo justo. Nunc semper, neque non pulvinar interdum, erat ex laoreet lacus.
```

What could be causing the removal of the original formatting?